# Is it possible to search and replace symbols in Notepad++ pairwise?

Tags: notepad++

For example, If I have `*ggg*`written on Notepad++. I want it to substitute the odd numbered `*`'s for `Pl` and the even numbered `*`'s for `Pk`. That is, after the replacement, it would be:

`PlgggPk`

Accross all the text. How can I do that? At the moment, I found only a way to substitute all the symbols.

Comment: Replace *ggg* with PlgggPk?

Comment: @Luc No, replace `*ggg*` with `PlgggPk`. The problem is that `ggg` could be anything, for example, consider the following block of text: `*gggg* is the best way to *www*`. I want it to substitute pairwise accross all the text, independently of what is inside the `**`.

Comment: Like search with regex `\*([^*]*)\*` and replace with `Pl\1Pk`? I'm not sure if that will work across lines and I can't test it right now, but if it doesn't this can be worked around

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using the regex replace from notepad++.
Go to the replace dialog

Find:    \*(.*)\*

Replace:Pl\1PK

Searchmode: Regular Expression

Comment: This will replace `*ggg*hhh*` with `PLggg*hhhPK` which is not what is wanted. The `.*` is **greedy*", you need to use a "*non*greedy*" expression or to use an "*anything except* `*`" expression.

Comment: I think it also need to have the first and last `*` escaped. When I tried `*(.*)*` in notepad++, I got a message the regular expression was invalid.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment to your question, this can be done by searching using regular expressions. I've now had time to verify my suggested regex.

In the "Find what" box, enter `\*([^*]*)\*`
This consists of three parts:

- `\*`: Match the symbol `*` (The `\` escapes the asterisk because it has special meaning in regular expressions); followed by
- `([^*]*)`: Any sequence of symbols other than `*`, capturing the matched sequence as group 1; followed by
- `\*`: another symbol `*`

In the "Replace with" box, enter `Pk\1Pl`. The `\1` is a reference to the captured group 1 between the two matched `*` symbols, i.e. the sequence of symbols other than `*`
Set the search mode to "Regex", and hit Replace All

Using this on the following input:

```
* lorem *
* ipsum
dolor *
* sit * amet *
*
* consectetur * adipisci * elit *
**
```

Results in the following:

```
Pk lorem Pl
Pk ipsum
dolor Pl
Pk sit Pl amet Pk
Pl
Pk consectetur Pl adipisci Pk elit Pl
PkPl
```